# Identity Server authentication with Azure AD - Http Header is larger than 10240 bytes

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I am integrating IdentityServer4 with AzureAd. I have configure AD authentication from this link - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3769bc41d625439f4ff94d2d8a4a247053c28037/host/Startup.cs#L77.  Everything is working fine except sometimes, when the request comes back from azure ad to identityserver, it fails with message - "Http Header is larger than 10240 bytes". This is happening randomly for some user but once it comes, it require manual deletion of idsrv.externalC1 cookie. So my guess is somehow this cookie is not getting deleted. I have tried using services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache option to store the state but there is no impact. Anybody have any idea?